# How do I repeat different kind of rows with different widths with css grid?

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I want to utilize css grid to display the following table using `repeat(x)` pattern:

- The blue boxes are the headings and only appear once. They should use auto width, based on the biggest blue/green box in the column.
- The green boxes also use auto width, based on the biggest blue/green box in the column.
- They yellow boxes take 100% width combining the width of all 3 columns.

The green + yellow boxes should be able to be repeated X number of times.

If this is not a good example to use grid, feel free to show a different alternative!

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually your layout can be achieved using only one rule:

```css
.container {
  display:grid;
  grid-gap:10px;
  grid-auto-rows:50px;
}

.container div {
  background:green;
}

/* the first 3 row (the heading) */
.container :nth-child(-n + 3) {
  background:purple;
}
/* the largest row */
.container :nth-child(4n + 7) { /* you pattern repeat each 4 items starting from the 7th */
  background:orange;
  grid-column:span 3; /* this rule will do everything */
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

> ***The blue boxes are the headings and only appear once. They should use
> auto width, based on the biggest blue/green box in the column.***

Depending on what your css is set to in regards to the parent elements width and height, the children within each row will be determined by the grid template columns/rows fraction you have set in your CSS. `grid-template-rows` `grid-template-columns`. If you have three columns each 1fr wide, they will span the width and gap set in your CSS for that row => `grid-template-areas: "el el el"` equals ***el + gap + el + gap + el*** = parents declared width in CSS.

> ***The yellow boxes take 100% width combining the width of all 3
> columns.***

In the case of your rows that only contain one element, the yellow rows, you want to lay those out in the grid-template-areas like `grid-template-areas: "row3 row3 row3"` where that elements ***class*** = `row3`.

> ***"The green + yellow boxes should be able to be repeated X number of times."***

*Using **grid layout** you will have to code your CSS to accommodate this.*

- Your HTML will have to reflect a class selector for each new row/elements in that row.
- The class selector for that new row will have to be added to the parent elements (***main*** in my example below) CSS `grid-template-areas:` ***and*** the `grid-template-rows: repeat(8, 1fr);` rule will have to reflect the correct number of repeated rows here => `repeat(8, 1fr)`, 8 being the number of rows in your layout.
- Each new row/elements within that row will need to have a ***grid-area*** set to their class selectors.

```css
:root {
  --orange: 242, 202, 4;
  --green: 85, 205, 75;
  --blue: 80, 137, 245;
}

#cont {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.main {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
  grid-template-rows: repeat(8, 1fr);
  gap: 20px 20px;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  min-height: 500px;
  grid-template-areas: 
    "col1-row1 col2-row1 col3-row1" 
    "col1-row2 col2-row2 col3-row2" 
    "row3 row3 row3" 
    "col1-row4 col2-row4 col3-row4" 
    "row5 row5 row5" 
    "col1-row6 col2-row6 col3-row6" 
    "row7 row7 row7" 
    ". bullets .";
}

.col1-row1 {
  grid-area: col1-row1;
  border: 2px solid rgb(var(--blue));
  background: rgba(var(--blue), 0.5);
}

.col2-row1 {
  grid-area: col2-row1;
  border: 2px solid rgb(var(--blue));
  background: rgba(var(--blue), 0.5);
}

.col3-row1 {
  grid-area: col3-row1;
  border: 2px solid rgb(var(--blue));
  background: rgba(var(--blue), 0.5);
}

.col1-row2 {
  grid-area: col1-row2;
  border: 2px solid rgb(var(--green));
  background: rgba(var(--green), 0.5);
}

.col2-row2 {
  grid-area: col2-row2;
  border: 2px solid rgb(var(--green));
  background: rgba(var(--green), 0.5);
}

.col3-row2 {
  grid-area: col3-row2;
  border: 2px solid rgb(var(--green));
  background: rgba(var(--green), 0.5);
}

.row3 {
  grid-area: row3;
  border: 2px solid rgb(var(--orange));
  background: rgba(var(--orange), 0.5);
}

.col1-row4 {
  grid-area: col1-row4;
  border: 2px solid rgb(var(--green));
  background: rgba(var(--green), 0.5);
}

.col2-row4 {
  grid-area: col2-row4;
  border: 2px solid rgb(var(--green));
  background: rgba(var(--green), 0.5);
}

.col3-row4 {
  grid-area: col3-row4;
  border: 2px solid rgb(var(--green));
  background: rgba(var(--green), 0.5);
}

.row5 {
  grid-area: row5;
  border: 2px solid rgb(var(--orange));
  background: rgba(var(--orange), 0.5);
}

.col1-row6 {
  grid-area: col1-row6;
  border: 2px solid rgb(var(--green));
  background: rgba(var(--green), 0.5);
}

.col2-row6 {
  grid-area: col2-row6;
  border: 2px solid rgb(var(--green));
  background: rgba(var(--green), 0.5);
}

.col3-row6 {
  grid-area: col3-row6;
  border: 2px solid rgb(var(--green));
  background: rgba(var(--green), 0.5);
}

.row7 {
  grid-area: row7;
  border: 2px solid rgb(var(--orange));
  background: rgba(var(--orange), 0.5);
}

.bullets {
  grid-area: bullets;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-items: end;
}
.bullets span {
  height: 10px;
  width: 10px;
  border: 2px solid #AAA;
  background: #CCC;
  border-radius: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div id="cont">
  <div class="main">
    <div class="col1-row1"></div>
    <div class="col2-row1"></div>
    <div class="col3-row1"></div>
    <div class="col1-row2"></div>
    <div class="col2-row2"></div>
    <div class="col3-row2"></div>
    <div class="row3"></div>
    <div class="col1-row4"></div>
    <div class="col2-row4"></div>
    <div class="col3-row4"></div>
    <div class="row5"></div>
    <div class="col1-row6"></div>
    <div class="col2-row6"></div>
    <div class="col3-row6"></div>
    <div class="row7"></div>
    <div class="bullets">
      <span></span>
      <span></span>
      <span></span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I extended @dale landry answer to make it more dynamic, without having to explicitly define each row in `grid-template-areas` and use `grid-column: span 3;` instead.

```css
:root {
  --yellow: 242, 202, 4;
  --green: 85, 205, 75;
  --blue: 80, 137, 245;
}

#cont {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.main {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto, auto, auto;
  gap: 10px 10px;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  min-height: 500px;
}
.box {
   height:50px;
}
.yellow-box {
  grid-column: span 3;
  border: 2px solid rgb(var(--yellow));
  background: rgba(var(--yellow), 0.5);
 }
.blue-box {
  border: 2px solid rgb(var(--blue));
  background: rgba(var(--blue), 0.5);
}

.green-box {
  border: 2px solid rgb(var(--green));
  background: rgba(var(--green), 0.5);
}
```

```html
<div id="cont">
  <div class="main">
    <div class="blue-box"></div>
    <div class="blue-box"></div>
    <div class="blue-box"></div>
    <div class="green-box"></div>
    <div class="green-box"></div>
    <div class="green-box"></div>
    <div class="yellow-box"></div>
    <div class="green-box"></div>
    <div class="green-box"></div>
    <div class="green-box"></div>
    <div class="yellow-box"></div>
    <div class="green-box"></div>
    <div class="green-box"></div>
    <div class="green-box"></div>
    <div class="yellow-box"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```